# JSON.parse SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: javascript, node.js

Trying to parse this data:

```
{ id: 'abc',
    name: 'abc',
    '24h_total': '370029.0',
    last_updated: '1501633446' }
```

Trying to run this code on the above rest api response.....

```
var jsondata =  JSON.parse(body);
var values = [];
console.log(jsondata);

for(var i=0; i< jsondata.length; i++){
     //how do i access this property?
     console.log(jsondata[i].24h_total);
}
```

at the moment i get an error

```
    jsondata[i].24h_total, 
               ^^^
```

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

I am sure it's due to the fact that this field name starts with a number.

thanks in advance.

Comment: that isn't valid JSON - see http://www.json.org/ - it would need to be `{"id":"abc","name":"abc","24h_total":"370029.0","last_updated":"1501633446"}` .. note ... all keys and all strings enclosed in `"..."` ... `'...'` is not valid JSON

Comment: Oh, wait, I see, you've misrepresented the actual JSON you have ... yes, it's the fact that variable names in JS can't start with a digit

Answer (score 2):

You need to access the property like so, because it's not a valid javascript identifier:

```
console.log(jsondata[i]['24h_total']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Access that property like so:

`jsondata[i]['24h_total']`

This will fix the error.